# JPA entity manyToOne null

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

I've got a problem with a jpa entity that could be null when i saved it.

I've an employe that can have a chief but it can also have no chief and that's my problem. When my employe have no chief, an error is displayed and i don't know how to resolve it.

> javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered new object in persistent field "patinfo.gestionprojet.ejb.EmployeBean.responsable" during attach. However, this field does not allow cascade attach. Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.MERGE or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "merge" or "all" (JPA orm.xml). You cannot attach a reference to a new object without cascading. FailedObject: patinfo.gestionprojet.ejb.EmployeBean@7a8f9cc4

I tried with the nullable paramter of @joincolumn but it doesn't change nothing.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_NoResponsable")
private EmployeBean responsable;
```

Does anyone have an idea ??

When i tried with the cascade attribure like that :

When i tried with this parameters,

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_NoResponsable")
private EmployeBean responsable;
```

This request is executed

```
INSERT INTO employe (EMP_Adresse, EMP_B13iemeSalaireInclus, EMP_BActif, 
        EMP_BAllocFam, EMP_BCongeClient, EMP_BConjointActLucrative, 
        EMP_BConjointAllocFam, EMP_BJoursFeriesInclus, EMP_BSalaireMensuel, 
        EMP_BVacancesIncluses, EMP_CantonHabitation, EMP_CasePostale, 
        EMP_DateDebutContrat, EMP_DateFinContrat, EMP_DateNaissance, 
        EMP_Deleted, EMP_DescriptionPoste, EMP_Email, EMP_EmailProf, 
        EMP_EmployeurConjoint, EMP_EtatCivilDateDebut, EMP_Localite, 
        EMP_Montant13iemeSalaire, EMP_MontantSalaire, EMP_NbHeuresSemaine, 
        EMP_NoAVS, EMP_NoFax, EMP_NoFaxProf, EMP_NoImmeuble, EMP_NoMobile, 
        EMP_NoMobileProf, EMP_NoTel, EMP_NoTelProf, EMP_Nom, EMP_Npa, 
        EMP_PermisSejour, EMP_Prenom, EMP_Sexe, EMP_TarifHeure, 
        EMP_TarifHeureCoutReel, EMP_TauxOccupation, EMP_TempsEssai, 
        EMP_TxActiviteConjoint, EMP_NoCanton, EMP_NoContact, EMP_NoEntreprise, 
        EMP_NoEtatCivil, EMP_NoNationalite, EMP_NoPays, EMP_NoResponsable) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
        ?, ?) 
[params=(null) null, (null) null, (int) 0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (int) 0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (int) 0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (float) 0.0, (float) 0.0, (float) 0.0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null]} [code=1048, state=23000]
```

And it's clearly not what i want..

To add:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void add(EmployeBean a) {
    getEntityManager().persist(a);
}
```

To modify:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public EmployeBean modify(EmployeBean a) {
    EmployeBean ret = getEntityManager().merge(a);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It rather seems that the problem is that you try to attach a new chief to an existing employee, without cascade, and without first persisting the new chief. Have you read the error message?

Comment: I also tried with the cascade but all my field of the employe bean took the value of null and i don't understand why...

Comment: We can't understand anything either if you don't post any code.

Comment: What kind of code do you like to see?

Comment: what about the code where you attempt to PERSIST the object(s)?!

Comment: "When an employee has no chief"  How does employee and chief relate to the EmployeBean.responsible self reference?  Is it null, or is your application putting in an EmployeeBean instance with null values?

Comment: It's putting an EmployeeBean with null values... And it's certainly the reason of this message. I'll try to change it and put null instead of a employeeBean with null values